# Why print statements inside rust `thread` do not run?

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency

I am reading about concurrency in Rust so created a cargo lib to test the code. I wrote this basic function

```
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    thread::spawn( || {
        // I created 20 lines of print statements in thread, none prints out
        println!("Hello 1, world  thread!");
        println!("Hello 2, world  thread!");
        println!("Hello 3, world  thread!");
    });
    // also 20 lines here, they all executed
    println!("Hello 1, world main function!");
    println!("Hello 2, world main function!");
}
```

Code compiles, only print statements after the `thread` are logged on the terminal. I run `cargo run` many times but still same result.

to increase the chance to thread switching, inside the thread, I have 20 lines of print statements and I also put 20 lines of print statements outside the thread. But none of the print statements inside thread logs. I expected to see mixed logs from the spawn thread and the main thread.

I want to test out that when I have too many print statements, I will see some print out from the spawn thread and some from the main thread in mixed order. But I do not see any print out from `spawn thread`. I can use

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
```

or `join.handle`

but I do not understand why I do not see the expected behavior in the first place

I am using Kali Linux. I suspect that this might be related to my linux os but I could not find anything online related to this.

Comment: please do not use `thread::sleep` instead of a proper solution like join handles or other concurrency structures to wait for a thread to finish. This introduces race conditions because we can never guarantee if the thread will exit by the time the sleep finishes. The OS scheduler may start the thread immediately on another core in your machine, but odds are it will need to wait for a time slot to become available. Your machine likely has hundreds or thousands of threads running at a given time across different applications and they are all waiting for CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

The program exits when the main thread ends. We can't say for sure which thread will exit first, but odds are it will be the thread that is already running. You can make the main thread wait for your other thread to finish by using the new thread's [`JoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html) to wait until it finishes before exiting the program.

```rust
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let join_handle = thread::spawn( || {
        println!("Hello 1, world  thread!");
        println!("Hello 2, world  thread!");
        println!("Hello 3, world  thread!");
    });
    println!("Hello 1, world main function!");
    println!("Hello 2, world main function!");
    
    // Wait until other thread has finished
    join_handle.join().expect("thread did not panic");
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5c575c3e3538c7e6aeb8157697c378e1)

Comment: I added 20 lines inside the thread and 20 outside, but none of the print statement run inside the thread. Isn't this odd?

Comment: @Yilmaz it sounds like you are getting into a deadlock somehow. If I had to guess, you may be locking a mutex on both threads. If I am correct, you need to make sure it is dropped before attempting to join the threads (it gets dropped at the end of the scope, so either put it in a separate code block or explicitly `drop(guard)`). Your OS should not have any effect on this.

Comment: @Yilmaz [The code in the answer works fine.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab8f7dbe6e3044be11b415ccb476e898) Please edit the question with the real code you are having issues with.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I want to test out that when I have too many print statements, I will see some print out from spawn thread and some from the main thread in mixed order.  I will update the question accordingly

Comment: @Yilmaz So you are wondering why the prints from the main thread and the spawned thread are not mixed? That's not really anything to write home about it. Thread scheduling is pretty arbitrary and there's a ton of things that influence it. That's threading 101...